# No files emitted Warning

Tags: coverity

I have C/C++ application and I am trying to run cov-build and getting a warning “ NO FILES EMITTED”. Can you please help me as we doing the POC on Coverity for static code analysis.

```
C:\Users\Master\bamboo-agent-home\xml-data\build-dir\DEC-L11PROJ-JOB1>cov-build --dir cov-int IarBuild.exe MainApplication\EWARM\L11_P4_uC1.ewp -build *
```

Coverity Build Capture (64-bit) version 2019.03 on Windows 10 Enterprise, 64-bit (build 18362)
Internal version numbers: 2c0f9c8cf4 p-pacific1-push-35439.872

```
 IAR Command Line Build Utility V8.4.8.6680
 Copyright 2002-2020 IAR Systems AB.
```

Total number of errors: 0
Total number of warnings: 0
[WARNING] No files were emitted. This may be due to a problem with your configuration
or because no files were actually compiled by your build command.
Please make sure you have configured the compilers actually used in the compilation.
For more details, please look at:
C:/Users/Master/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/DEC-L11PROJ-JOB1/cov-int/build-log.txt

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are involved in a pre-sales Proof of Concept (POC), then there should be a Coverity Sales Engineer assigned to help with the POC.  That person's role includes providing instructions and information similar to what I'll offer below, as well as answering technical questions such as yours.  There may have been a miscommunication somewhere.  **Get in contact with the Sales Engineer**, as they will be able to help more reliably and completely than I can.

Now, what's going on?  The primary purpose of `cov-build` is to watch the build process for invocations of compilers, and when one is found, compile the same code using the Coverity compiler (called `cov-emit`).  But in order to recognize a compiler, `cov-build` needs to know its command line name, what kind of compiler it is, where its include files are stored, etc.  This is accomplished by a helper tool called `cov-configure` that must be run before `cov-build`.  If `cov-configure` has not been run, then no compiler invocations will be recognized, which appears to be the case for you, as indicated by "No files were emitted".

Synopsys has a page called [CLI Integration Cheat sheet](https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/cli-integration-cheatsheet) that gives these commands for use with IAR:

```
cov-configure --comptype iar:arm --compiler iccarm --template
cov-build --dir <intermediate directory> "c:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 6.5\common\bin\IarBuild.exe" sample_project.ewp -build Debug -log all
```

I can't personally vouch for these commands (I don't have IAR, nor access to the Coverity tools anymore; I'm a former employee), but something like that will be needed.  Again, your assigned Sales Engineer should be able to help.

Finally, for new Coverity users, I recommend using the `cov-wizard` tool.  `cov-wizard` is a graphical front-end to the command line tools, and has help text explaining the concepts and procedures, along with a convenient interface for performing them.  There are several steps even after `cov-build`, and `cov-wizard` will walk you through all of them.  Its final screen shows exactly what command lines it used in case you want to script them.